# JAVA - How to convert sexagesimal and plot as a line?

Tags: java, plot, mapping, line, graphics2d

What I am hoping to figure out is how you would convert the following sexagesimal type of direction: N. 00 deg. 23' 44" E. 290.40 feet, and then plot a draw a line based on the bearing, direction and distance from that. You would basically have a series of these in order plot out the boundaries. Hope that makes sense. Any pseudo-code, ideas, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No idea what you're using to plot. Can you not convert both to inches?

Answer (score 0):

Some **code** mixed with **Pseudocode**:

```
//Using OpenGL

glLineWidth(1);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //starting point

// convert to degrees (i think this is right)
var angle = -23 - 44 = 63; 
//  maybe the '' is a decimal not NE so would be
angle = -23.44;

//then do some simple trig to find where point 2 lies


// (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) = m

// √[(x2 - x1)² + (y2 - y1)²] = 290.40; // (d for distance)

// to obtain:

// x2 = x1 ± d/√(m² + 1)

// y2 = y1 ± (md)/√(m² + 1) // m for slope


glLineTo(x2,y2, 0);
//or
glVertex3f(x2, y2, 0);
glEnd();

// use this if you need to move the line starting point...
glMoveTo()
```

Maths from http://www.mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=15926